# PyQt - Loading multiple UI files

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt, maya

I have multiple ui files, each created in Qt Designer.  I have a function (main) that calls the first UI. There is a button on this first UI that calls the second UI and closes the first one.

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore, uic

uifile_1 = '/Users/Shared/Autodesk/maya/scripts/python/Intro_UI.ui'
form_1, base_1 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_1)

uifile_2 = '/Users/Shared/Autodesk/maya/scripts/python/objtemplate_tuner.ui'
form_2, base_2 = uic.loadUiType(uifile_2)

class CreateUI_2(base_2, form_2):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_2,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

class CreateUI_1(base_1, form_1):
    def __init__(self):
        super(base_1,self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.Establish_Connections()

    def Do_ButtonPress(self):        
        UI_2=CreateUI_2()
        UI_2.show()
        self.close()
    def Establish_Connections(self):
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.noncharactermeshes_Button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.Do_ButtonPress)      

def main():       
    UI_1 = CreateUI_1()
    UI_1.show()

main()
```

The problem is that when I run main() nothing happens.  Also note I'm creating this script for Maya and using PyQt4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer, turns out I needed to use a global variable for my ui.

```
    def Do_ButtonPress(self):
        global UI_2
        UI_2=CreateUI_2()
        UI_2.show()
```

...

```
def main():
    global UI_1
    UI_1 = CreateUI_1()
    UI_1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Maya, Qt may or may not already be running as an application.

Autodesk started introducing Qt into their software a few years ago, and the latest Maya is almost entirely Qt driven.

Judging from the fact that you can run your code without a crash, I'm assuming that a QApplication exists somewhere already under the hood.  It is important to note that you cannot create any QtGui components (well, QPaintDevice's - so QWidget, QDialog, QMainWindow, etc.) without first creating a QApplication, or you'll get a crash.

The fact that you aren't seeing anything means you're either in a Maya version that uses Qt (and initialized a QApplication) but does not run its event loop - or there is a parenting issue.

I'd switch your main function to look like this first:

```
def main():
    app = None
    # there needs to be 1 and only 1 application instance
    if ( not QtGui.QApplication.instance() ):
        app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    UI_1 = CreateUI_1()
    UI_1.show()

    # see if you can parent to a window (maya)
    UI_1.setParent(QtGui.QApplication.activeWindow())
```

If that does not work, then you will need to update the Qt event loop within maya's event loop.  I don't remember the syntax for that...but ultimately you will need to use maya's callback system to update the Qt events:

```
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().processEvents()
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try... but unfortunatly it crashes Maya :(

Comment: Its probably creating a second QApplication.  You need to check to see if the QApplication.instance() exists or not first.  Usually, its easiest to start this using the python shell and test things out.  What version of maya are you using?